# Simulating traffic noise in Python

Tags: audio-processing

I am trying to simulate traffic noise for doing some measurements in Acoustic Vehicle Alerting Systems (AVAS).

I am trying to figure out whether this can be done in the form of additive or multiplicative noise?

Comment: Microphones are (as far as we usually try to use them) linear, and so is air as medium: like all sounds, acoustic noise is additive.

Comment: Why don't you download some measured traffic noise files from something like a free sound effect website?

Comment: That's great, I was heading towards this direction too.